# Find normalized vectors / versors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

I need to find all normalized vectors / versors at $(1,-1)$ for the following function:
$$ f(x,y)=x^3-y^3 $$

---

I got $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{v}} (1,-1)= \lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{(1+tv_x)^3-(tv_y-1)^3 -(1+1)}{t} \\
3v_x-3v_y=0 \implies 
v_x=v_y$$
and $$v_x^2+v_y^2=1$$
thus $\vec{v}=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ or  $\vec{v}=(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$

Is it a correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by 'normalized vectors', you mean all the normal vectors to the surface $f(x,y)$ at $(1,-1)$? A normal vector to the surface given by $f(x,y)$ will be $\nabla\! f$. But we want a unit vector, so the vector we want is $\vec{n}= \dfrac{\nabla\! f}{\|\nabla\! f\|}$. We find
$$
\begin{split}
\nabla\! f& = \langle 3x^2, -3y^2 \rangle \bigg|_{(1,-1)}=\langle 3,-3 \rangle \\
\|\nabla\! f\|&= \sqrt{9x^4+9y^4}= 3 \sqrt{x^4+y^4} \;\bigg|_{(1,-1)}= 3\sqrt{2}
\end{split}
$$
But then a unit normal vector would be
$$
\vec{n}= \dfrac{\nabla\! f}{\|\nabla\! f\|}= \dfrac{\langle 3,-3\rangle}{3\sqrt{2}}= \dfrac{3\langle 1,-1 \rangle}{3 \sqrt{2}}= \left\langle \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right\rangle
$$
Of course, the 'reflection' of this vector is also a possible unit normal vector, so then we must have
$$
\vec{n}= \pm \left\langle \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right\rangle
$$
So you are close, I assume there is a sign error somewhere. Although, I am not quite sure of the method as I do not know what you mean by $\partial f/\partial \vec{v}$, as I do not see how $f(x,y)$ depends on $\vec{v}$ for the partial to make sense.

Comment: That is the notation used in my textbook for the directional derivative $∂f/∂\vec v(x_0,y_0):=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{f(x_0+tv_x,y_0+tv_y)-f(x_0,y_0)}{t}$
$\vec v$ is a unit vector.

Comment: @Patrycja I see. I have never seen this notation before but from context, it seemed like this was the case given your limit and the problem 'type'.